# How to debug/list all OpenTelemetry targets scraped into a k8s cluster

Tags: kubernetes, open-telemetry

I'm configuring OpenTelemetry on a k8s cluster with the following configuration

```
- job_name: MYAPP
  kubernetes_sd_configs:
  - role: pod
  metrics_path: /metrics
  scrape_interval: 10s
  relabel_configs:
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_namespace]
    action: keep
    regex: (myapp.*|custom.*)
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_namespace]
    action: replace
    target_label: namespace
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_name]
    action: replace
    target_label: pod
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_name, __meta_kubernetes_pod_ip]
    action: replace
    regex: (.*);(.*)
    replacement: $${2}-$${1}
    target_label: instance
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_container_image]
    action: replace
    target_label: image
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_container_name]
    action: replace
    target_label: container
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_ip]
    action: replace
    regex: (.*)
    replacement: $${1}:3000
    target_label: __address__
```

All my microservices expose on `http://<ip>:3000/metrics` applications metrics.
My cluster has 8 nodes with more then 100 microservices.

How can I debug/list all targets detected by OpenTelemetry?

I need it because randomly, even if all the services are up & running, I miss metrics, and it seems that kubernetes_sd_configs is not using some targets.

So how to debug if scraping is working well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use/process/monitor `up` metric in the Prometheus:

```
up{job="<job-name>", instance="<instance-id>"}: 1 if the instance is healthy, i.e. reachable, or 0 if the scrape failed.
```

So in your case it can be:

```
up{job="MYAPP"}
```

Comment: Great, thank you! I've just created an `instant` query on grafana `up == 0` and it works perfect!!!